# Get data-attribute jquery vs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a custom data-attribute set by default:

`data-equipment="0"`

If i change it with jquery using **.data()**

`$(this).data("equipment", 10)`

and then use the **getAttribute()**

`this.getAttribute("data-equipment")`

i get the old value (0) and not the new one (10). But if i use

`$(this).data("equipment")` i get the new value (10).

Is this supposed to work like this or am i missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: The `.data()` doesn't truly  support data attributes. It just grabs the value from the attribute then uses its own data storage to hold it without ever updating the attribute. I personally wouldn't use jQuery's `.data()` for this.

Comment: data- attributes are accessible using element.dataset which i beleive is not used by jQuery.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`.data()` doesn't operate on data attributes but in internal jQuery cache. Initially if no cache record is found, the data is read from a corresponding `data-` attribute if one exists, but that is the end of their co-operation.

If it operated on attributes, it would be useless for its purpose because attribute values must be strings.

Comment: I think this is the main difference between `$(this).data("equipment")` and  `$(this).attr("data-equipment")`. If you retrieve some data attribute with `$(this).data("equipment")` and change attribute value with `$(this).attr("data-equipment", "some value")`, then you cannot retrieve new value with `$(this).data("equipment")` due to the caching mechanism of jQuery.