# Rails Progress Job with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, progress-bar, bootstrap-4

I found [this gem](https://github.com/d4be4st/progress_job) to use the bootstrap progress bar and the delayed job gem together. In his example he uses .haml file, but I'm using erb and coffeescript in my project, so I tried to reproduce what he does.

This is my **controller**

```
def export
    @job = Delayed::Job.enqueue StandingsJob.new
end
```

this is **routes.rb**

```
get 'export', to: 'scraper#export'
```

and this is my **home.erb.html**

```
<%= link_to 'export', export_path, {id:'mario', remote: true} %>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
       aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
    0%
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my **coffeescript** file

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
    $('#mario').on 'click', ->
      alert('hocliccatoooo')
      interval = setInterval( ->
        $.ajax(
          url: '/progress-job/' **** What should I add here?????****,
          success: (job) ->
            console.log('loool')
            stage
            progress
            if job.last_error != null
              $('.progress-status').addClass('text-danger').text(job.progress_stage);
              $('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-danger');
              $('.progress').removeClass('active');
              clearInterval(interval);

            if job.progress_stage != null
                stage = job.progress_stage
                progress = job.progress_current / job.progress_max * 100
            else
              progress = 0
              stage = 'Uploading file?'

            if progress != 0
              $('.progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%').text(progress + '%')
            $('.progress-status').text(stage);
          error: ->
            alert('errore')
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
            $('.progress-bar').css('width', '100%').text('100%');
            $('.progress-status').text('Finito!!!');
            clearInterval(interval);

        )
      , 100)
```

The code runs correctly when I click on the link, the only problem is, how can I tell to my coffeescript the id of the job that I created in my controller action?
Thank you all

[EDIT]

This is my **job**

```
class StandingsJob < ProgressJob::Base

  def perform
    update_stage 'Faccio cose'
    update_progress_max 10
    for i in [0..10]
      sleep(2)
      update_progress
    end
  end
end
```

I did some digging and seems that the perfom method of my job is never fired(i put a puts 'lol' in my perform method and I never see it in the console)

Answer (score 1):

interval = setInterval( ->
   var paramJob = '<%=@job.to_json%>'; // get @job parameter ->

//use the string "&" + "quot;" instead of SYM

var jobObj = JSON.parse(('{' + paramJob.slice(paramJob.indexOf("SYMid"), paramJob.length)).replace(/SYM/g, '"'));//The parameters are processed

//in the ajax use  jobObj.id
url: '/progress-job/' + jobObj.id,

hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side vs server side issue.

You'll have to put the job-id in a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) on the html tag during the server side render. It should be in the @job variable based on your controller action.

Once your page is rendered and you're in the coffeescript code (now client side). [You can parse this attribute out and utilize it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18107213/793330)